# bfastts for monthly data

Tags: r, time-series, na

I am working with data collected monthly. In my dataset, there are some months where no data was collected and thus, there is no entry in my data. I have previously used `bfastts` for similar occurrences when data was collected daily, so that I may have NA values in my data. How may I do the same for monthly data, using `bfastts` or some other function?

eg. below if needed

```
2006-06-01 2.260121

2006-07-01 2.306800

2006-08-01 2.246624

2006-09-01 1.724565

2006-11-01 1.630561

2007-05-01 2.228918

2007-06-01 2.228918

2007-07-01 2.22891
```

I wish to have NA fields for December to March.

Answer (score 0):

The question did not specify what class of object is desired but here are three.    zoo supports an irregularly spaced index so it does not need to insert NA's but ts does not and converting from zoo to ts automatically inserts NA's.   Convert the ts object back to zoo again or to a data frame to get a zoo or data frame object with NA's.

The zoo and data frame objects use yearmon class for the index which internally represents year/month as year + fraction where fraction is 0, 1/12, ..., 11/12 for Jan, Feb, ..., Dec and displays in meaningful form.  as.Date can be used to convert yearmon objects to Date objects although in this case yearmon probably makes more sense since it directly represents year and month without day.

If you want to go in the other direction and remove NA's use `na.omit(z_na)` or `na.omit(DF_na)` .

```
library(zoo)

# zoo object - no NA's
z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon)

# ts object with NA's
tt <- as.ts(z)

# zoo object with NA's
z_na <- as.zoo(tt)

# data.frame with NA's
DF_na <- fortify.zoo(tt)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "2006-06-01 2.260121
2006-07-01 2.306800
2006-08-01 2.246624
2006-09-01 1.724565
2006-11-01 1.630561
2007-05-01 2.228918
2007-06-01 2.228918
2007-07-01 2.22891"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```